# Why does imshow report errors in different locations and VideoWriter.write also report errors

Tags: c++, opencv, qt6

I am using Qt version 6.2.4, and I am making a simple video processing software. I need to take every frame of the video and perform a series of OpenCV operations on that frame. Here is my code to get each frame of the image:

Here is some explanation of my code:

1. `processVideoFrame` slot function is used to get each frame of the video in response to the signal.
2. I used a `std::vector` to store every frame of the cv::Mat type, where my **QImage was converted to cv::Mat** and then `push_back` into mats
3. In the `positionChanged` signal, if the time reaches the end of the video, it indicates that the video is finished playing, and then the showMats function is called to show each frame that I have stored before

To make sure it doesn't end immediately, I've added `cv::waitKey` to pause it. In theory, my `showMats` function should reproduce the video by going through each Mat, but it's reporting an error at imshow.

```cpp
class VideoFrameProcessor : public QObject
{
public:
    VideoFrameProcessor(QLabel* label) : videoLabel(label) { 
        mats.clear(); 
        videoWrite.open("video/output.mp4", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 25, cv::Size(1566, 1080), true);
    }
    ~VideoFrameProcessor() {
        videoWrite.release();
    }
    void showMats() {
        for (auto& frame : mats) {
            if (frame.empty() || cv::waitKey(10) == 27) {
                break;
            }
            //cv::imshow("1", frame);  //When I use it, I get an error
        }
    }
public slots:
    void processVideoFrame(const QVideoFrame& frame)
    {
        if (frame.isValid())
        {
            QImage image = frame.toImage();
            height = image.height();
            width = image.width();
            cv::Mat mt(image.height(), image.width(), CV_8UC4,image.bits(),image.bytesPerLine());
            mats.push_back(mt);
            cv::imshow("1", mt); // When I use it, it's correct

           //
           //videoWrite.write(mt);
        }
    }
private:
    cv::VideoWriter videoWrite;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> mats; 
    int height, width;
    QLabel* videoLabel;
};

class VideoWidget : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    VideoWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        resize(640, 480);
        QLabel* videoLabel = new QLabel(this);
        videoLabel->show();

        mediaPlayer = new QMediaPlayer(this);
        videoWidget = new QVideoWidget(this);
        mediaPlayer->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
        videoWidget->show();

        // 设置要播放的视频文件
        mediaPlayer->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("video/cat.mp4"));

        // 播放视频
        mediaPlayer->play();

        // 创建QVideoSink并连接到videoFrameChanged信号
        videoSink = new QVideoSink(this);
        frameProcessor = new VideoFrameProcessor(videoLabel);
        QObject::connect(videoSink, &QVideoSink::videoFrameChanged, frameProcessor, &VideoFrameProcessor::processVideoFrame);
        mediaPlayer->setVideoSink(videoSink);

        connect(mediaPlayer, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, this, [=](qint64 val) {
            if (val == mediaPlayer->duration()) {
                //Show a series of Mats
                frameProcessor->showMats();
            }
            });

        this->setCentralWidget(videoWidget);
    }
    
private:
    
    QMediaPlayer* mediaPlayer;
    QVideoWidget* videoWidget;
    QVideoSink* videoSink;
    VideoFrameProcessor* frameProcessor;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    VideoWidget w;
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

[This is an error image after my imshow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHr8T.png)
And output the error code:  -1073741819。

As far as I know: std::vector data does not automatically disappear. The data will remain until your program exits or you explicitly release them.

So I also used an imshow in the `processVideoFrame` function to display the image at any time, and this time it worked.
As you can see, this video is of a cat:
[This is the correct video frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGnXM.jpg)

I want to know why imshow will report errors in different positions?

Comment: mixing GUIs is illegal. you can't mix imshow with any GUI toolkits.

Comment: I have removed the second question from your question. Please ask **one** question per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get segmentation fault because you use `cv::Mat` constructor [version](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a) which only stories a reference to already allocated data i.e. the data created and owned by `QImage` (we can say that image data are shared between `QImage` and `cv::Mat`).

> data  Pointer to the user data. Matrix constructors that take data and
> step parameters do not allocate matrix data. Instead, they just
> initialize the matrix header that points to the specified data, which
> means that no data is copied. This operation is very efficient and can
> be used to process external data using OpenCV functions. The external
> data is not automatically deallocated, so you should take care of it.

Becuase `QImage` is local, when the code goes out of the scope local `QImage` is destroyed and `cv::Mat` holds dangling pointer.

```
        QImage image = frame.toImage();
        height = image.height();
        width = image.width();
        cv::Mat mt(image.height(), image.width(), CV_8UC4,image.bits(),image.bytesPerLine());
        mats.push_back(mt);
```

to make the code working, call `clone`:

```
mats.push_back(mt.clone());
```

by `clong` the deep copy of data shared by `mat/qimage` is done.